# Customising Sharp-Architecture Code Generation WizardImplementation

Tags: .net, code-generation, s#arp-architecture

I have a solution where I have two web projects instead of one. One for front-end and one for the back-end. Now, I am running into problems when I try to generate code as it looks for the default Web project `WhatEverTheSolutionName.Web` But I don't have it as I renamed it to `WhatEverTheSolutionName.FrontEnd.Web` and also created another web layer called `WhatEverTheSolutionName.BackEnd.Web` under the app folder.

My application works fine, its just the code generation that is failing as it obvious that it does not know about my customisation of the layers.

Now, I would like to know how can I change WizardImplementation class implementation to accommodate this as I cannot run it in debug mode. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Regards
Robie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robie,
     You would need to Modify the ScaffoldingGenerator.tt file. Specifically the calls to GenerateControllerAndTests() and GenerateViews()

Comment: Many thanks Alec. You are doing a great work. I enjoy working with Sharp-Arch.